# Есть ли разница между вызовом функции из другой функции и "возвратом" функции из функции через return?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли разница между двумя следующими вызовами функции из другой функции? Здесь ф-ия called() просто должна отработать, засовывать ее куда то еще для использования механизма замыкания не планируется. Интересует разница именно в контексте "просто вызвать функцию из другой функции".

```
function caller() {
    return called();
}

function caller() {
    called();
}
```

Comment: Разница есть, в первом случае вы возвращаете значение, во втором - нет.

Comment: возврат функции это `return called` а у вас возврат значения полученного из `called()`. Если вам надо просто вызвать  функцию, то без разницы как вы это напишите.  То есть возврат функции это `return function(){..}`, тогда будет возвращена функция, которую вы можете далее вызвать. В вашем же коде, вы простовы зываете функции, так что в заголовке вопроса какая-то путаница.

Comment: @teran, да, вы правы, я действительно ошибся в формулировке вопроса. Т.е. пример я привел правильный, меня интересовала именно разница между    called() и    return called()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница есть, в первом случае вы возвращаете значение, во втором - нет. пример ниже.

```js
function called()
{
  return 1
}

function caller1() {
    return called();
}

function caller2() {
    called();
}

function caller3() {
  var a=called();
  return a; 
}

function caller4() {
  return called;
}

console.log(caller1());
console.log(caller2());
console.log(caller3());
console.log(caller4());
```

Примеры 1 и 3 - равнозначны, что демонстрирует одинаковое выполнение функции called() в обоих случаях вызова.
Т.е. **return** никак не влияет на поведение **вызываемой** функции.

Comment: Это и так понятно. Возможно стоило уточнить в вопросе, я на момент написания думал о этих функциях как об обработчиках, всм, что мне нужно, чтобы ф-ия сработала и все, без дальнейших действий. Но все равно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Serafim, в зависимости от примера разница может быть, а может и не быть, добавь в вопрос более конкретный пример

Comment: @Serafim ответ именно на вопрос, если вас интересовало выполнится ли код функций - он выполнится, return - делает возврат ответа, к выполнению функции он не имеет отношения, сейчас поправлю ответ.